# Capistrano and deployment of a website from Github

Tags: deployment, capistrano, web-deployment

So, I had what I thought was a fairly simple Capistrano use case: I want to deploy a PHP site from Github. But I'm running into a lot of problems. When I run `cap deploy`, Capistrano is able to clone the Github repo (the `deploy:update_code` step), but then in the `deploy:finalize_update` step it says

```
executing "rm -rf /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/log /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/system /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/tmp &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/sitename.com/shared/log /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/log &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/sitename.com/shared/system /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/system &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/sitename.com/shared/pids /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/tmp/pids"
```

followed by

```
executing "find /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/images /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/stylesheets /var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201006111445.23 {} ';'; true"
```

I don't really understand what's going on here. It then gives an error:

```
*** [err :: sitename.com] find: `/var/www/sitename.com/releases/20100611144519/public/images': No such file or directory
```

and another error for each of the `stylesheets` and `javascripts` directories.

What's going on? I realize that Capistrano is primarily for deploying Rails and other Ruby apps, but I'm using the [capistrano-php](http://github.com/namics/capistrano-php) gem. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Capistrano default behavior is to 'touch' all assets files. (To make sure that any cache get the deployment date). Assets are images, stylesheets, etc.

If your PHP application is not using these directories, capistrano complains in such an ugly way.

To disable asset timestamps updates, simply add:

```
 set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
```

to your deploy.rb

Comment: This also resolved the errors I was getting on a Rails 3.1 application.  I assume this is no longer needed with the asset pipeline.