# No such file or directory in capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Here is the error when doing cap deploy:

```
*** [err :: 11.15.19.46] find: `/var/www/emclab/releases/20111208184942/public/images'
*** [err :: 11.15.19.46] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: 11.15.19.46] find: `/var/www/emclab/releases/20111208184942/public/stylesheets': No such file or directory
*** [err :: 11.15.19.46] find: `/var/www/emclab/releases/20111208184942/public/javascripts'
*** [err :: 11.15.19.46] : No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts what causes the error? thanks.

Answer (score 35):

I assume you updated to rails 3.1

I run in same problem recently. Solution:

Add this line to deploy.rb

```
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
```

In fact this question is duplication of: [Capistrano and deployment of a website from Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023857/capistrano-and-deployment-of-a-website-from-github)

only post it because found it on google quite high and this one has not got answer

Answer (score 11):

I struggled with this problem also.

Assuming you are using Rails 3.1, the answer is on this webpage: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

The short answer is your assets (imgs, js, css) haven't been compiled for deployment to production. You can either compile them manually with this command.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Or you can uncomment this line from your Capfile:

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Or you can set your production environment to compile the assets in production, but I found that solution just created more problems and would recommend the two suggestions above.

Comment: adding load 'deploy/assets' to deploy.rb was enough for me :-)